# Reading from a .txt file into a structure in C++ language

Tags: c++, file-handling

Is there a way to import the content of my text file into a structure?

My code looks like this:

```
struct customerstruct {
    int Customer_ID;
    string name;
    string adress;
};
```

And this is the content of my text file:

```
101
James
221B Baker St.
```

I would like to mirror the value of my text file into the structure.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: [**Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66639412/edit) the question and add your code.

Comment: You do this in the same way as you would if you had three separate variables, but you write `structvariablename.membername` instead of `variablename`.

Comment: The data is suspect, at that address the name should either be John or Sherlock, not James.

Comment: Please search the internet for "C++ read file struct".  There are a lot of similar questions and answers already.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:

```
struct customerstruct
{
    int Customer_ID;
    string name;
    string adress;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, customerstruct & c);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, customerstruct & c)
{
    input >> c.Customer_ID;
    input.ignore(1000, '\n');
    std::getline(input, c.name);
    std::getline(input, c.adress);
    return input;
}
```

Your input loop could look like this:

```
customerstruct c;
std::vector<customerstruct> database;
while (my_file >> c)
{
    database.push_back(c);
}
```

The structure overloads `operator>>` to reading a single instance.
A `std::vector` is used to contain more than one instance read from a file.